# pybind11: what python data structure for a c++ unsigned char*?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, pybind11

A c++ function has a signature:

```
void f*(unsigned char* buffer, int buffer_size);
```

It can be wrapped using pybind11:

```
m.def("f",&f);
```

I am now stuck on how I may call `f` in python.

For example, using ctypes, something like this would work:

```py
buffer = bytearray(size)
cbuf_type = ctypes.c_char*len(buffer)
cbuf = cbuf_type.from_buffer(buffer)
lib.f(cbuf,size)
```

What would work for pybind11 ?

Answer (score 0):

One simply has to use the interoperability with numpy, here an example:

[https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/cspy/18G_C++_Python_pybind11.html#Using-numpy-arrays-as-function-arguments-and-return-values](https://people.duke.edu/%7Eccc14/cspy/18G_C++_Python_pybind11.html#Using-numpy-arrays-as-function-arguments-and-return-values)